# Acoustics in heterogeneous medium: Reflection and Tranmission

Tags: acoustics, reflection

I am trying to understand the effect of changing impedance on acoustic pressure wave. I have attached the image from the book "Fundamentals of Acoustics"(Kinsler et. al)(r1 and r2 are the impedance of two mediums). As per the statement, when wave travel from low to high impedance material the amplitude of transmitted wave increases. Could anyone explain to me what is the physical significance of increasing transmitted amplitude? In terms of energy, I understand that the more the impedance contrast more energy will be reflected back. But strictly speaking, I would like the understand the significance of an increase in transmitted pressure wave amplitude. Does that mean the sound will amplify as the wave goes from air to water?

[image: Wave propagation across different mediums]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acoustics: Reflection and Transmission Coefficients](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485470/acoustics-reflection-and-transmission-coefficients)

Comment: Wave is travelling from low to high impedance. Specifically I would like to know the significance of increasing amplitude. I understand in terms of power, it is decreasing. But is there any inference that we can make out of increasing amplitude of pressure wave.

Comment: I already answered that question to you in the other post. Besides, why does it have to be intuitive? It is what it is. I would say that your major problem is understanding the concept of impedance.